# Single line has_many_through create command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

These are our models:

**app/models/ice_cream.rb**

```
class IceCream < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :sundaes, through: :ingredients
end
```

**app/models/sundae.rb**

```
class Sundae < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :ice_creams, through: :ingredients
end
```

**app/models/ingredient.rb**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ice_cream
  belongs_to :sundae
end
```

We use the following code to create a new `Sundae` with two ingredients:

```
IceCream.create(name: 'chocolate')
IceCream.create(name: 'vanilla')

Sundae.create(name: 'abc')
Sundae.first.ingredients.create(ice_cream: IceCream.first, quantity: 2)
Sundae.first.ingredients.create(ice_cream: IceCream.last, quantity: 1)
```

Is it possible to write the last three lines of code as one single command? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Sundae.create(name: 'abc', ingredients: [Ingredient.create(ice_cream: IceCream.first, quantity: 2), Ingredient.create(ice_cream: IceCream.last, quantity: 1)])
```

as `ActiveRecord` will add a function `ingredients=` in the `Sundae` class when you use `has_many` for `ingredients`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, too:

```
Sundae.create(name: 'abc').tap{ |sundae| sundae.ingredients.create([{ice_cream: IceCream.first, quantity: 2}, {ice_cream: IceCream.first, quantity: 1}])}
```